# Не могу создать SQL запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite3, aiogram

Нужно сделать, чтобы тг бот писал юзеру его статус(который равен 0 или 1). Я не шарю в sql и сам пайтон изучаю 5 день, мне нужно возращать в bot.py из sqlcfg.py переменную status, значение которой будет браться из базы. После бота думаю прочитать учебник по sql, если можете, то посоветуйте какой-нибудь. Код прилагаю:

```
    def check_user_status(self, user_id, status):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT `status` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (status, )).fetchall()
```

После этого хз что писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить из базы значение одной записи используйте `fetchone`

Так вытаскиваем статус юзера из базы, проверяем что данные в таблице нашлись и после сравниваем `status`, переданный в функцию, с статусом из базы:

```py
sql = "SELECT `status` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `user_id` = ?"
rs = self.cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, )).fetchone()
user_status = rs[0] if rs else None
return user_status == status
```

А так проверяем, что есть в базе такой юзер и с таким статусом (если не найдется, то вернет `None`):

```py
sql = "SELECT 1 FROM `userinfo` WHERE `user_id` = ? and status = ?"
rs = self.cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, status)).fetchone()
return bool(rs)
```

Comment: Хм, я знал про fetchone, но не понимал как его юзать. Вписал, как ты сказал, сейчас выдаёт эту ошибку: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Чувствую, что где-то ответ рядом, но не могу докопаться до истины

Comment: @Daniil, это значит, что не было найдено данных с таким user_id, нужно добавить проверку rs. Добавлю пример. Например, если добавить `if not rs:`, то так проверите что ничего не нашлось, типа: `if not rs: print(f"Не найден пользователь с {user_id}!")`. СТОП, а почему у вас в user_id передается status?

Comment: @Daniil, обновил ответ

Comment: В каком месте передаётся status в user_id?

Comment: status не передается в user_id, status берется из аргумента функции в `check_user_status(self, user_id, status)`, если вы про запрос sql, то это в `status = ?`

Comment: def check_user_status(self, user_id, status):
        with self.connection:
            sql = "SELECT `status` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `user_id` = ?"
            rs = self.cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, )).fetchone()
            user_status = rs[0] if rs else None
            return user_status == status написал так, теперь выдаёт module 'sqlcfg' has no attribute 'status'

Comment: Не знаю откуда тут взялся модуль `sqlcfg`, это у вас так файл назван? `sqlcfg.py`?

Comment: Да, в нём инструкции для работы с БД, бот в другом файле берёт из sqlcfg переменную status

Comment: @Daniil, значит не смог взять. Переменная status в таком случае должна быть глобальной для того файла. Но это вряд ли правильно. Скорее всего, вам нужно это значение из функции возвращать

Comment: @Daniil, если мой код в ответе помог с проблемой, то [проголосуйте и отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)